# How much should I tip movers?

Tags: united-states, household, moving

Are there any rules of thumb for tipping movers who load truck on one day and deliver on the next day?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends upon where you are in the United States but I've heard everything not tipping them in the case of a fairly straightforward move to up to $50 per mover if they are outstanding in terms of performance or you have an especially complex move for some reason.

In the New England area the rule of thumb seems to be that you should have some sort of beverage (i.e. water, soda, etc) on hand to offer them while they are loading and unloading the truck or packing and then once the move is complete to tip them between $20 and $50 per person.

In general though, avoid giving them a tip as a percentage of the cost of the move and give the tip directly to each person as opposed to the foreman to be split among the movers.

Comment: This is a move in the Southeast in August. Having drinks on hand is a great idea.

Comment: Whenever I have a work crew over I like to provide food or drinks.  When I had my roof replaced I went and bought 10 breakfast burritos ($20).  I want the people who work for me to know that I value them which will usually drive them to do better work.

Comment: When we last moved (13 years ago) the crew at the small company we used worked like crazy, full speed the entire time and no breaks.  At the same time they were very careful, and didn't break or damage anything. We were very impressed.  One of us went out and got lunch (a bunch of 10 pack taco bell tacos If I recall) and some lemonaid. and we tipped each guy like $20 when they were done.  We also recommended the company to all our friends and co-workers.